# Make plot of parametric function with piecewise components

Tags: plotting, piecewise

How can I plot this curve in *Mathematica*:

$\begin{align}
x(t)&=\begin {cases} 2 (t-n+1) \: , \: t\in [n-1,n-1/2] \\ 2-2 (t-n+1) \: , \: t\in [n-1/2, n] \end {cases}\\
y(t)&=\begin {cases} 2 (\sqrt {2}t-n+1) \: , \: \sqrt {2} t\in [n-1,n-1/2] \\ 2-2 ( \sqrt {2} t-n+1) \: , \: \sqrt {2} t\in [n-1/2, n] \end {cases}
\end{align}$

with $ n\in \mathbb{N} $

Comment: You've seen `Mod[]` already?

Comment: When posting code you should paste Mathematica code from your notebook as described [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody followed up on my hint, here goes.

Noting that $y(t)=x(\sqrt 2 t)$, it suffices to define only $x(t)$.

A slight tweaking of the definition in the OP allows one to express the function in terms of `Mod[]`. However, it is actually more convenient to use `QuotientRemainder[]` instead, so I've employed it here:

```
x[t_] := Module[{nm, r}, {nm, r} = QuotientRemainder[t, 1]; 
                Piecewise[{{2 r, nm <= t < nm + 1/2},
                           {2 - 2 r, nm + 1/2 <= t < nm + 1}}]]
```

However, some more thought, assisted by looking at a plot of the function, suggests a more compact expression:

```
x[t_] := (1 + TriangleWave[t - 1/4])/2
```

Here then is a plot of the desired parametric equation:

```
ParametricPlot[{x[t], x[Sqrt[2] t]}, {t, 0, 20}, PlotPoints -> 95]
```

[image: looks kinda messy to me]

Answer (score 3):

I am not quite certain what you mean by

```
t ∈ [n - 1, n - 1/2]
```

and similar constructs in your question.

I am interpreting it to mean that for a particular `n` you will have two functions that cover the range `{n-1, n-1/2}` and `{n-1/2, n-1}`.

If my interpretation is incorrect, this answer may not help you.

You can make plots for various values of `n` using `Manipulate`.

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
  ParametricPlot[{2 (t - n + 1), 2 (2 Sqrt[t] - n + 1)}, {t, n - 1, 
    n - 1/2}, PlotStyle -> Blue],
  ParametricPlot[{2 - 2 (t - n + 1), 2 - 2 (2 Sqrt[t] - n + 1)}, {t, 
    n - 1/1, n}, PlotStyle -> Red],
  PlotRange -> All,
  AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio
  ],
 {{n, 1}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I define the curve on [0,+\infty) Jack :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your problem. See if you can re-formulate it to make it crystal clear the problem that you are experiencing.